# background image sprite hover not aligning

Tags: html, css

I am trying to implement background image sprite hover effect from this CSS-tricks article: http://css-tricks.com/fade-image-within-sprite/

My problem is that the images do not align completely in the following case:

HTML:

```
<ul class="contact">
    <li class="phone"><a class="bg_hover" href="#">Call me</a>

    </li>
    <li class="twitter"><a class="bg_hover" href="#">Follow me on Twitter</a>

    </li>
    <li class="email"><a class="bg_hover" href="#">Email me</a>

    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.bg_hover {
    position: relative;
}
.bg_hover:after {
    content:"";
    background-image: inherit;
    background-position: bottom left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    transition: 1s;
}
.bg_hover:hover:after {
    opacity: 1;
}
.contact {
    margin-left: 60px;
}
.contact li {
    float:left;
    margin: 30px 15px 0 0;
    font-style: italic;
}
.contact li a {
    padding: 3px 0 0 25px;
    height: 18px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
}
.contact .phone a {
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/9d9hdiL.png);
}
.contact .email a {
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/9d9hdiL.png);
}
.contact .twitter a {
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/9d9hdiL.png);
}
li {
    list-style: none;
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/47Lngd4t/2/

[image]

Can you tell me where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your background-position isn't quite right. The image sprite you used is a pixel or two out. Change `background-position` to the following:

```
.bg_hover:after {
    background-position: 0 -21px;
}
```

See demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/AndyMardell/47Lngd4t/3/

Answer (score 0):

If You're talking about effect like here http://take.ms/a6ar2 simply add `line-height` for example `10px` to `.contact li a` selector

There are also some other ways to get effect:

- You can change padding of `<a>` elements
- You can change `background-position` of image

Comment: I edited the question with a picture so you can see the effect I meant.

Comment: Ok, so here You have working fiddle with line-height solution http://jsfiddle.net/47Lngd4t/4/

Answer (score 0):

I changed

```
.contact li a {
padding: 3px 0 0 25px;
...
}
```

to

```
.contact li a {
padding: 2px 0 0 25px;
...
}
```

So, from 3px to 2px. Seems to align for me.